# jQuery: Can't get the submit button to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am familiar with JavaScript but new to jQuery and very lost at the moment. I realise this question has been asked before, but I am not clear on how to solve this one. I am creating a dialog box with a submit button. When the submit button is clicked, it should direct to the function ’getUsername()’. I tested the code in JavaScript and I got it to work successfully, but can’t get the same result with the jQuery dialog box. The dialog box shows, with the text input and submit button, but clicking the button doesn't yield any result.

This is the html code:

```
<body onload="showDialog()">
        <form id="usernameInput" action="" onsubmit="return getUsername()">
            <br><br>
             <input type="text" id="usernameBox" required>
             <input type="submit" value="Start chatting!">
         </form>
     </div>
</body>
```

and this is the script:

```
 function showDialog(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "form" ).dialog({
            open: function() {
            $( this ).find( "[type=submit]" ).hide(); },
            title: 'Enter username',
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            modal: false,
            buttons: [{
                text: "Start chatting!",
                click: $.noop,
                type: "submit"
            }
            ]
        });

    });     
  }
```

Comment: where is getusername??

Comment: Of course the button doesn't do anything, you're passing `$.noop` as its `click` handler.

Comment: and you hide the button ```$( this ).find( "[type=submit]" ).hide();```

Comment: are you able to see submit button as it seems it is getting hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the submit button is created outside the form, so the automatic form submit won't work

```
function showDialog() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").dialog({
            open: function () {
                $(this).find("[type=submit]").hide();
            },
            title: 'Enter username',
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            modal: false,
            buttons: [{
                text: "Start chatting!",
                click: function(){
                    $("form").submit()
                },
                type: "submit"
            }]
        });

    });
}
```

See the dom structure

[image: DOM of the Dialog]

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jzwK3/)